# Force light theme on Android for Appcelerator Titanium app

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

After updating the Android SDK API to version 29 on an old app, one "picker" gets messed up if the Android phone is set to the dark theme, everything else is fine, but this one picker shows the text with a white font color and the options with a dark background.

If the Android theme is Light, the colors for this picker are just fine. This is the only customization I have on the theme:

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#00699C</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#0095da</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#ffcb08</item>
  </style>
</resource>
```

And this is the Picker code:

```
<View platform='android' top='0' height='53' backgroundColor='Alloy.Globals.colors.GRAY_LIGHT_4'>
  <Picker id="picker" left='5' right='5' top='5' bottom='5' selectionIndicator="true" onChange="filterChange">
    <PickerColumn id="column1">
      <PickerRow title='Option 1'/>
      <PickerRow title='Option 2'/>
      <PickerRow title='Option 3'/>
    </PickerColumn>
  </Picker>
</View>
```

How can I force this app to use only the Light Theme?

I'm using Titanium SDK version `8.3.1.GA`

Edit:

The problem was that my MainActivity was using the `Theme.Titanium` changing it to my theme solved the picker problem, but now the tabs that had the labels in white are in black.

```
<activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MondeActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

Looks like that the picker problem is a bug in the `Theme.Titanium`.

Comment: do you specify the maxSdkVersion level inside tiapp.xml? Dark mode is available in 29+ so it shouldn't do anything if you set it to max 28. Full dark mode support will come in 9.1.0

Comment: I tested it now but didn't work. The problem is when I use the "Theme.Titanium", if I use the `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` directly the picker options are fine but then my tabs titles are changed from white to black and I can't figure out how to make them white again.